# Is there any method for lazyloading for custom marker from URL in Google Map v2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

We have implemented Google Map v2 and all markers we are getting from URL but it will take more time to plot on the map.

In Google Map v1 there is method of Lazyloading like we are doing lazyloading in imageview.

So in Google Map v2 is there any method or any code to lazy loading of markers on the map.

Comment: used AsyncTask for Background loading

Comment: Do you have any sample code or link of code ?